# How do I write functions that modify operations in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

In Q#'s [type documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/type-model?view=qsharp-preview#operation-and-function-types), it is mentioned that you can create signatures like this:

```
function ConjugateInvertibleWith : (inner: ((Qubit[] => Unit) : Adjoint),
                                    outer : ((Qubit[] => Unit) : Adjoint))
                                 : ((Qubit[] => Unit) : Adjoint)
```

My question is: how is this function actually implemented.

Presumably a function with this name will return an operation that, when invoked, calls outer, then inner, then adjoint outer. However, I have no idea how to actually write a function like this. In particular, it's not clear how to write the equivalent of a lambda with a closure. For example, if I try to declare an operation inside a function (similar to how you can def inside a def in python), I get a syntax error.

Does this have to be done in a non-Q# library, like in C#, then imported into Q#? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this example, one obtains a function with that signature by partial application of an operation that is defined outside the body, instead of as a lambda in the function. As a concrete example, consider this non-generic version of the WithA operation, modified from [Q# canon](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/blob/master/Standard/src/Canon/Combinators/With.qs).

```
operation WithA(
    outer : (Qubit[] => Unit : Adjoint), 
    inner : (Qubit[] => Unit : Adjoint), 
    target : Qubit[]) 
    : Unit
{
    body (...)
    {
        outer(target);
        inner(target);
        Adjoint outer(target);
    }
    adjoint invert;
}
```

This applies the sequence $|\textrm{target}\rangle\rightarrow\textrm{outer}^\dagger\cdot\textrm{inner}\cdot\textrm{outer}|\textrm{target}\rangle$.

We can then [partially apply the target](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/expressions?view=qsharp-preview#partial-application), by using the underscore character in place of an argument, to create the desired signature as follows.

```
function WithAFunction(
    outer : (Qubit[] => Unit : Adjoint), 
    inner : (Qubit[] => Unit : Adjoint)) 
    : ((Qubit[] => Unit) : Adjoint)
{
    return WithA(outer, inner, _);
}
```